# how to export variable correctly in SConstript

Tags: scons

I have a directory:

```
src
   sconscript
   main
       sconstruct
       main.cpp
```

In the sconscript, I write

```
env=Environment(CXX='g++',LINK='g++')
```

In the sconstruct, I write

```
SConscript('../sconscript',exports='env')
Import('env')
env.Program(target='a.out',source='main.cpp')
```

And then I go to directory src/main and type scons -Q, it just complains:

```
Export of non-existent variable ''env''
```

From http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user.html#idm139837640372096, I think the syntax is correct. So what is the problem?

I use ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.12 and scons 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SConscript should read

```
env=Environment(CXX='g++',LINK='g++')
Return('env')
```

Your SConstruct should read

```
env = SConscript('../sconscript')
env.Program(target='a.out',source='main.cpp')
```

Take a look at the manpage:
http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

Comment: Thank you. It works. But my original scons code exactly follows the scons user guide, do you have any idea why it not work?

Comment: @ken I'm looking at the section you linked to and it really does't follow the users guide. "Once a variable has been exported from a calling SConscript file, it may be used in other SConscript files by calling the Import function:"